# Adding Header in ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I need add header in my listview and header should always displayed even scrolling list.

Is it possible in android list view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution that works for me is to create a TableLayout that has a row with the heading and a row with the list like this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <include layout="@layout/header" />

   <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</TableLayout>
```

Please make sure that the ListView has @android:id/list as the ID.

Comment: Please use match_parent instead of fill_parent because its deprecated in material design

Answer (score 7):

you can add header in list view like this:

```
View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)Activity.this.getSystemService(Activity.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
list.addHeaderView(headerView)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, here is what i 've done:

[image: showcase]

For a custom layout with `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`, your layout must contain a `ListView` with the `android:id` attribute set to `@android:id/list`.

1) `main_layout.xml`:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    // custom Headers
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/systolic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/diastolic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/date" />
    </LinearLayout>

    // This is important to be exactly like below ,android:id="@android:id/list"

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

For custom layout for each row of list,

2) `custom_list_row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpSysHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpDiaHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpDtHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

3) `ListActivity`:

```
public class HistoryActivity extends ListActivity {
        private SimpleCursorAdapter dbAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // this is neccessery for you
            setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

            dao = new BpDAO(this);

            Cursor bpList = dao.fetchAll_bp();

            String[] from = new String[] { BpDAO.bp_SYS, BpDAO.bp_DIA, BpDAO.bp_DT };
            int[] target = new int[] { R.id.bpSysHolder, R.id.bpDiaHolder,
                    R.id.bpDtHolder };

            // And this for custom row layout for each list row
            dbAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_row,
                    bpList, from, target);

            setListAdapter(dbAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            dao.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO something on item click

        }
    }
```

---

In case you need it check: "[Attaching a sticky (fixed) header/footer to a listview](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/)"

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing. Put one TextView just above the list view and set text as your header .It will achieve your need.